# I am getting a "fatal error 7987" error from SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

The error happens trying to do an insert from a stored proc.  I tried running DBCC CHECKDB as suggested by the kb article that Jonathan Holland suggested and it returned with the all clear.

Answer (score 4):

Bummer dude.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828337

Answer (score 2):

Ran a **dbcc dbreindex ('tablename')** against the tables that were being affected by the stored procedure that was being called.  This forced all of the pages to be moved, which appears to have corrected the problem.  This would indicate it was a page corruption that the DBCC CHECKDB didn't catch.